# How can i append event.stopPropogation() in inline element function call

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to add `event.stopPropogation()` in inline `onclick()` function before `remove_e('+i+' )` function..

Like this...

```
onclick(event.StopPropogating(); remove_e();)
```

but when i add this it doesnot work...

Broken code:

```
$(".select2-selection__rendered").append('<li class="select2-selection__choice" id="remove_test'+i+'"  title="'+rows_value+'"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" onclick="remove_e('+i+');" role="presentation">x</span>'+title_name_test+'</li> ');
```

Comment: You tried onclick="event.StopPropogation(); remove_e('+i+');"?

Comment: @Tushar Shahi yes i try this but it doesn't work...

Comment: Can you check, because i see a typo in your code in question.

Comment: @Tushar Shahi Code is working fine and have no error. Actually i want to stop parent div onclick event occuring when child onclick event occur...

Comment: You've misspelled "propagation"

Comment: @pointu may i enter here wrong spell but in code i enter correct spell. But problem still exist.